# How is a student perceived if he took more time to graduate?

Tags: phd, united-states

Suppose, a student completed his MSc in 4 years, instead of 2 years, but has a CGPA of **A**.

Would he have any disadvantage as a Ph.D. applicant?

**Edit:**
I can think of two possible reasons:
 1. financial difficulty.
 2. took some time to develop the necessary knowledge to cope with some courses. For instance, he has to complete a course ***X*** (e.g. Stochastic Process) but found that he doesn't have the necessary background knowledge (e.g. Probability and Statistics) to obtain a good score. So, he took some time studied at home and then came back, and he scored an **A** or **A+**.

Comment: No can say about how people or universities would feel. Could you be more specific to get an answer?

Comment: I think this question is quite clear:  Would taking 4 years rather than 2 be  viewed negatively by a PhD admissions committee?  I cannot fathom why anyone views this question as too broad.  It's a simple yes or no question that should be answerable by those who've served on PhD admissions committees.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton: As long as there is not at least a country tag, maybe even more specific information, it doesn't seem clear to me at all which expectations on the variability of MSc duration can be applied.

Comment: @NicoleHamilton this question is too broad.  In my field, and in some countries but not others, getting any kind of masters is a mistake.  It also depends on if the student was full time or half time, or any other reasons why it took two extra years.

Comment: What if the student had a prestigious corporate lab or consulting job while they were getting the master's, which made it take longer?  In that case, taking longer might be an advantage.

Comment: A student that completed an MSc in 4 years, rather than the expected 2 years, would (regularly) be disadvantaged against any student that completed in the expected 2 years and achieved the same or better grade.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist the question still seems fine to me. What I'm getting from your comments is that the answer is "it depends on the reason for the extra two years", which is absolutely a suitable answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

> Would he have **any** disadvantage as a PhD applicant?

Yes of course. But how big this disadvantage is, or if it is even relevant at all, depends on many factors:

- country
- field
- courses taken (that might actually be an advantage!)
- reason for the long time
- was that long time used properly (e.g. to produce a really good Master Thesis)
- other applicants
- how common an A-Master is in your field/country/at your university
- ...

I would personally say that the disadvantage is not that big, but that is only my personal opinion, and chances are low that I will sit in your PhD admission committee...
I don't see how you would be able to get a general answer even when providing all these answers and I would suggest asking someone who knows your situation (e.g. your advisor, if you already have one).

Comment: I don't think it deserves a full answer, but - the norm with which I grew up and which was drilled in me for years (east of Europe) was that _only_ people who do their studies in time can ever be considered _excellent_ students (deserving to continue their studies for example). Anything less and you cap yourself at _good_ (also the reason I never did an exchange during masters: bad organization, etc., I'd probably gain experience but lose a year). I was delighted to find out that manyplace in Europe, much more diverse paths (years off, years employed, changing fields) are completely accepted.